# Why do I need to mount Docker volumes for both php and nginx? And how to copy for production?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

I have a simple Laravel application with Nginx, PHP and MySQL each in its own container. What I don't understand is:

1. why do I need to mount volumes for both my Nginx and also PHP? Isn't PHP only a programming language not a server?
2. Also, for production do I need to COPY my src to `/var/www/html`, but do I need to do it for both Nginx and PHP? Or only for Nginx?

Here is my `docker-compose-dev.yml` file:

```
version: '3'

networks:
  laravel:

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine

    container_name: nginxcontainer

    ports:
      - "8088:80"

    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql

    networks:
      - laravel

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.22

    container_name: mysqlcontainer

    restart: unless-stopped

    tty: true

    ports:
      - "4306:3306"

    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql

    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: homestead
      MYSQL_USER: homestead
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql

    networks:
      - laravel

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: php/Dockerfile-dev

    container_name: phpcontainer

    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html

    ports:
      - "9000:9000"

    networks:
      - laravel
```

and here is my `php/Docker-dev` file:

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm-alpine

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
RUN chmod 755 /var/www
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you need to provide your sources for both nginx and php is rather simple. 
The webserver needs all of your assets (images, stylesheets, javascript etc.) so that it can serve them to the client.
PHP is interpreted serverside hence it requires your PHP source files and any referenced file (configs etc.) in order to execute them. In this case you are using PHP-**FPM** which is decoupled from the webserver and runs in a standalone fashion.

Many projects cleanly seperate frontend and backend code and only provide the frontend sources to the webserver and the backend code to the PHP container.

Another quick tip regarding docker: It is generally a good idea to compact RUN statements in the Dockerfile to avoid excessive layers in the image. Your Dockerfile could be compacted to:

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm-alpine

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql \
    && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www \
    && chmod 755 /var/www
```