# Why aren't mime types applied according to nginx.conf in Docker?

Tags: php, docker, nginx, mime-types

I can't figure out why my index.php is served correctly, but the mime-type for my assets keeps being served as text/html even though my nginx.conf has the necessary include directive for mime types. Here's my docker-compose.yml file.

```
services:
  #nginx
  web:
    image: nginx:latest 
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
  #php
  app:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./php/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app/
  #mysql
  #redis
```

And here's my nginx.conf

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {

    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    #keepalive_timeout  65;

  server {

    listen 8888;
    server_name localhost;
    root /app/public;
    index index.php;
    location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_pass app:9000;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
      
  }

}
```

Could it be the case that nginx is using a different config?

Comment: Do the resources actually work? In other words, does the CSS file your browser receives from Nginx contain the expected CSS code or does it contain code you would expect from your index.php file?

Comment: No, they don't and that's how I found it out. My entire view is loaded to a div to be rendered by React JS, but the code is not there. The console says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'", which is quite typical for mime type issues, and when I check the headers I can see the wrong mime type in the response. I thought adding the include directive for mime types would work but it hasn't so far.

Comment: Sorry, I left behind the final line. To summarize, it contains code I would expect from my index.php file.

Comment: Okay. The reason this happens is that you haven’t (also) mounted your application to `/app` in your Nginx container. Since the resources don’t actually exist locally for Nginx, the `try_files` directive kicks in and sends everything to index.php. You need to mount your app folder to `/app` in both your PHP *and* Nginx containers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I need to mount Docker volumes for both php and nginx? And how to copy for production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59439559/why-do-i-need-to-mount-docker-volumes-for-both-php-and-nginx-and-how-to-copy-fo)